# In an HTML select tag, can I display different values in the dropdown and in the selected label?

Tags: html

I have a country selector
In the dropdown I want to have a list of items like 'United States (+1)'
But when one is selected, I want the select tag to display something like 'US'

Is there a way to do this without using jQuery?

Comment: Without using jQuery: yes. Without using JavaScript: I don't think so (and certainly not with just HTML).

Comment: So you want the expanded list to say "United States (+1)", but after it's selected you want the dropdown to say "US"?